# Ajax em projeto diferente

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho um projeto em Asp.Net MVC com o seguinte método:

```
public ActionResult ObterCursos()
{
    List<curso> cursos = new List<curso>();

    curso curso_ = new curso();
    curso_.Nome = "Análise";
    curso_.Periodo = 3;
    curso_.qtdSemestre = 5;
    curso_.Codigo = "ADS";

    cursos.Add(curso_);

    curso_ = new curso();
    curso_.Nome = "Ciencia da Computação";
    curso_.Periodo = 3;
    curso_.qtdSemestre = 8;
    curso_.Codigo = "CDC";

    cursos.Add(curso_);

    return Json(cursos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Como podem ver, ele retorna um `Json` como resultado. Estou rodando tal projeto em minha máquina local.

Em outro projeto, estou tentando fazer uma requisição Ajax ao método criado no projeto anteriormente descrito.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:10642/Mobile/ObterCursos",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(dados) {
        resultado = dados;
        alert("json sucess")
    },
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
        alert("erro json: " + xhr.responseText)
    }
});
```

Ao ser executado, o `alert` de **erro** é mostrado e o seguinte erro é exibido no console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:10642/Mobile/ObterCursos.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Realizando minhas pesquisas, descobri que deveria alterar o `dataType` do `Ajax` para `jsonp`. E assim o fiz, mas o `alert` de **erro** ainda é mostrado, no entanto o erro que era exibido no `console` não aparece mais.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Isto aqui: `url : "http://localhost:10642/Mobile/ObterCursos",`é má prática. Troque para: `/Mobile/ObterCursos`.

Comment: O problema @CiganoMorrisonMendez é que como eu disse no problema, o Ajax está sendo executado em um outro projeto.

Comment: Continua sendo má prática. O correto é que o começo do endereço venha do `Web.config`.

Comment: Bem @CiganoMorrisonMendez o problema é que nesse meu projeto onde está o Ajax é um projeto `Cordova`, neste caso como eu poderia configurar o `Web.config`?

Comment: Acho que o ideal seria abrir uma pergunta só para isso. São alguns poucos passos, mas é pertinente a separação.

Comment: Opa @CiganoMorrisonMendez abri a pergunta bem [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67671/como-configurar-o-web-config-em-projeto-cordova).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse erro é causado por você estar fazendo uma requisição ajax de um domínio diferente, provavelmente no seu caso é somente a porta que difere, pois ambos devem estar no localhost.

Para resolver de vez, basta adicionar o header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` na resposta do servidor. Um jeito de fazer isso é adicionar a seguinte seção no arquivo Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>

    <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
       <clear />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Nesse caso o com atributo `value="*"` você está liberando o acesso para qualquer domínio, mas pode liberar para domínios específicos trocando o `*` pelo nome do domínio (no seu caso `localhost:porta` para ambiente de desenvolvimento).

---

Outro jeito de adicionar o header é usando um filtro

```
public class AllowOriginAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Então, adicione o atributo no método do Controller:

```
[AllowOrigin]
public ActionResult ObterCursos()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @MarcusVinicius, mas infelizmente o problema persiste. Deixe-me esclarecer um pouco melhor minha situação. Tenho um projeto Web Asp.Net MVC onde roda um site normalmente, e agora criei um novo controler chamado Mobile onde quero disponibilizar os Jsons para um aplicativo que irá rodar nos celulares por aí. Estou desenvolvendo tal aplicativo (que inclusive já conta com contribuições sua) usando o Cordova e realizando os testes em meu navegador apenas com as páginas HTML e o servidor IIS do projeto Web rodando.

Comment: Imaginei que este era o seu cenário. Adicionei uma alternativa que pode funcionar melhor com o MVC, inclusive por permitir adicionar o header por método.

Comment: Mais uma vez muito obrigado pelo empenho em ajudar a solucionar meu problema @MarcusVinicius, mas infelizmente o problema persiste. O engraçado é que coloquei um `breakpoint` no método `ObterCursos` no `Controller` de meu projeto MVC e a requisição está chegando até lá. O problema, acredito eu, deve estar no meu `Ajax`.

Comment: Você já debugou o que retorna no seu ajax? Você pode debugar js com IE ou ir colocando alert() em determinados pontos e ver o que está sendo retornando no seu ajax.

Comment: Olá @pnet, obrigado pela ajuda, mas já debuguei sim com IE. A requisição do Ajax chega no meu `controller` faz tudo direitinho, mas quando volta pro Ajax com os resultados o `alert` de **erro** é exibido.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, só precisei desativar o `async` do `Ajax`.