# Como configurar o Web.config em projeto Cordova?

Tags: apache-cordova, web.config

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67612/ajax-em-projeto-diferente?noredirect=1#comment138056_67612) fui recomendado a configurar o web.config do [meu projeto Cordova](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil) que usa Ajax. Pesquisei sobre o assunto mas não encontrei nada do tipo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defina no seu `Web.config` o seguinte:

```cs
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="BaseURL" value="http://localhost:12345/" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Recuperando a informação:

```cs
using System.Configuration;

var baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
```

Ao realizar o deploy, a informação pode ser mudada através de arquivos de transformação. No projeto, são criados dois como exemplo: `Web.debug.config` e `Web.Release.config`. No caso, para trocar `BaseURL`, a configuração fica da seguinte forma para um arquivo `Web.Release.config`:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseURL" value="http://urldomeusite.com.br" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez pela resposta @Cigano, [nesse comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67612/ajax-em-projeto-diferente/67617?noredirect=1#comment138042_67617) explico melhor o meu senário. O projeto em cordova pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil). Eu não intendi bem, mas essas configurações devo fazer no meu projeto Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Sim, exatamente. Como a configuração é variável, na hora de publicar o projeto, o próprio `Web.config` será alterado automaticamente.

Comment: Mas isso não traz risco para o restante do meu projeto? E no meu projeto Cordova não preciso fazer nada?

Comment: Que riscos? Poderia me exemplificar?

Comment: Bem o que faz basicamente essa alteração?

Comment: Como eu te falei, a configuração faz com que você possa usar valores variáveis para configuração de, por exemplo, a URL base da sua aplicação. Ao enviar para a produção, é óbvio que um endereço baseado em `localhost` não irá funcionar.

Comment: Amigo, suponhamos que eu tenha um arquivo .html que acabei de criar no bloco de notas com um código Ajax para obter os dados gerados por [esta aplicação](http://horariofacil.azurewebsites.net/Mobile/ObterCursos). Coloco um breakpoint na aplicação e a requisição está chegando normalmente, mas após isso a mensagem de erro do Ajax é gerado, o que poderia ser? Você teria um exemplo para obter os dados do link citado?

Comment: Por favor, faça outra pergunta.

Comment: A nova pergunta foi feita [neste link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67954/como-obter-json-por-ajax-em-html).