# Como obter Json por Ajax em .html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Suponhamos que eu tenha um arquivo `.html` que acabei de criar no bloco de notas com um código `Ajax` onde quero obter os dados gerados por [esta aplicação](http://horariofacil.azurewebsites.net/Mobile/ObterCursos). 
Fiz um código aqui, e quando coloco um `breakpoint` na aplicação percebo que a requisição está chegando normalmente, mas após isso a mensagem de erro do `Ajax` é gerado, o que poderia ser? Alguém teria um exemplo para obter os dados do link citado?

Comment: A solução pode ter jQuery?

Comment: Sim @MaiconCarraro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Utilize o [`getJson`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```js
$.getJSON( "http://horariofacil.azurewebsites.net/Mobile/ObterCursos", function(data) {
  var items = [];

  // each é pra iterar uma lista de dados
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) { 

    // key é o indice (0, 1, ..)
    // val é o objeto, no seu caso o curso

    // push adiciona o valor ao array
    items.push( "<li id='" + val.Codigo + "'>" + val.Nome + "</li>" );

  });
    
  // crio um elemento <ul>
  $( "<ul/>", {

    // função join transforma o array em uma string
    // html: seria o conteudo do <ul> 
    html: items.join( "" ) 

  }).appendTo( "body" ); // appendTo vai adicionar o <ul> ao <body>
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, você não imagina o quanto me ajudou! Funcionou perfeitamente, mas você poderia explicar um pouquinho mais seu código para que eu possa entender bem?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues prontinho :D

Comment: você é fera, muito obrigado mesmo mais uma vez, mas só tem um último problema. A questão do sincronismo, preciso retornar os valores obtidos. Veja [este código](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/Dao/cursosDao.js) por exemplo eu preciso apresentar os resultados [aqui](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/cursos.html#L68), você poderia me ajudar mais uma vez?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Eu fiz um código para retornar exatamente os botões que você precisa mostrar http://pastebin.com/EPvzC5V7

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo por sua ajuda. O que estava faltando ela somente definir o ajax como sincrono: 
`$.ajaxSetup({
   async : false
  })`